# Geometry Problem, see description for problem

Tags: geometry

Problem: Let ABCD be a trapezoid with bases AD and BC. Let |AB| = |BD|, M be the midpoint of CD, and O be the point of intersection of AC and BM. Show that the triangle BOC is isosceles.

My work: So far, I extended BM to a point N such that |BM| = |MN|

I am not really sure where to go from there, could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Extend BM so it intersects AD (its extension) at N. Then, since CM=MD and BM=MN and vertical angles BMD and CMN are equal, triangles BMD and CMN are congruent and  CN=BD. Therefore, given that AB=BD, the trapezoid ABCN is isosceles and angles BAD and BCN are supplementary. Therefore, A,B,C and N lie on a circle. Because of that, angles BNA and ACB are congruent (inscribed on a common chord AB. But angles BNA and CBN are also equal, being alternate. Conclusion: BCA and CBN are congruent and then triangle BCO is isosceles.

Comment: Simply extending BM to cut AD extended at N does not guarantee BM = MN.

Comment: Yes, it does. When you extend, the triangles MDN and BMS are clearly congruent (they have equal angles, since BC is parallel to AN, and their angles are alternate (recall BC is parallel to AN), and of course the vertical angles BMC and DMN are equal also) and they have one corresponding equal side, CM=MD because M is the midpoint. Therefore, BM=MN as corresponding sides in congruent triangles.

Comment: Surely they will be equal but I just want to say that the result is not so immediate.